# Does this sculpture of Lord Shiva really exist somewhere?

Tags: shiva, temple, identification-request, shiva-purana

[image]

Does this sculpture of Lord Shiva really exist somewhere? Or is this only a painting. I found it online many weeks ago and have been awe-struck by its sheer beauty. I would like to visit the place which (possibly) houses this sculpture someday.

Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rishikesh (from google search)

Comment: @user2225190 Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a real statue and was visarjit on 10 sept 2011. After that a new statue of shiva was placed on the [same site](https://www.google.com/search?sa=X&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN858IN858&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=667&sxsrf=ALeKk00RIzwKS7lALFPZOAnL3EJABkCHAA:1594734162381&q=shiva%20statue%20rishikesh&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=30119395,78311427,0&tbm=lcl&ved=2ahUKEwjd34na78zqAhXDfn0KHaJ_AJ8QtgN6BAgKEAQ&rldoc=1).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!